# fill array from json file without knowing the keys

Tags: java, simplejson

I have the following Json file and I want to create list of array ,**i don't know the keys name** (like person ,lastname etc ) it can be
many entities like employes users etc but the structure of the file must be **exactly** the same ,how can i do that ?

the file is

```
{
    "Person": [
        {
            "name": "Peter",
            "lastname": "ta",
            "age": 43,
            "sex": "male"
        },
        {
            "name": "Zara",
            "lastname": "treg",
            "age": 25,
            "sex": "female"
        }
    ]
}
```

what I need is to create list of array like this

```
person ,name,peter ,lastname,ta,age,43,sex,male
person ,name,zara ,lastname,treg,age,23,sex,female
```

....

I started with the following code to get the file but since i dont know the name of the keys I dont know how to proceed.

```
JSONObject jsonObject= (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\General\\jsonperson.txt"));
```

Comment: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#names() "Produce a JSONArray containing the names of the elements of this JSONObject." http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys() "Get an enumeration of the keys of the JSONObject." Neither of those will work for you? Also, please be more specific about the platform and library you are using. I had to guess.

Comment: im using simplejson,can you provide an example please?

Comment: "simplejson" is for python. You tagged this Java...

Comment: Im using java maybe its not simple json...

Comment: Gonna assume he meant https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Example 4 on this page: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples

Specifically, this part:

```
Map json = (Map)parser.parse(jsonText, containerFactory);
Iterator iter = json.entrySet().iterator();
System.out.println("==iterate result==");
while(iter.hasNext()){
  Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)iter.next();
  System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=>" + entry.getValue());
}

System.out.println("==toJSONString()==");
System.out.println(JSONValue.toJSONString(json));
```

That's how you might iterate over the entries of a `JSONObject`. By the way, with this library, if it's the one I think you're using, a `JSONObject` is just a [`java.util.Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), and you can use all of its methods - that's why it works for this example to cast the parse result to a `Map`.

All of the JSON <-> Java object mappings for this lib: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/MappingBetweenJSONAndJavaEntities

Comment: thanks ,how should i change the file to text ,im using JSONObject jsonObject= (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\General\\jsonperson.txt")); and i getting object...

Comment: Did you not understand the example? The first line I quoted does precisely the same thing, except that it casts it to a Map instead.

Comment: It should still work... Did you try it? Also, you haven't confirmed yet that this is the same library that you're working with.

Comment: I try it and now its working,i just changed the text with the object toString Map json = (Map) parser1.parse(jsonObject.toString(), containerFactory);,btw why the while run just one time ,i have added to the file additional data and it still run just one time,there is a way to run with loop for every array entry of the file?

Comment: If you take the time to try and understand what is going on with the code, it may become apparent to you how to do that. I would also encourage you to look up examples of using Map objects and looping, since it seems you don't have the best intuition yet about those. Also, look through the other examples on the JSON-simple page: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples Hopefully that will give you a better idea of what it's actually doing. If, after that, you still have questions, then try to make your question as specific as possible and include code demonstrating it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
String[] keyNames= JSONObject.getNames(jsonObject);
```

to get the names of the keys.
[Javadoc](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getNames(org.json.JSONObject))

Using this, you can get the values using [getJSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject(java.lang.String))

Looping these you can construct the array you are looking for.

Comment: This is for modifying in Java since the original post was tagged in Java.

Comment: Yes, someone mistakenly retagged it as Python. OP clearly said it's Java. I fixed it. It does still matter which library it is, though.

Comment: @Harsh - thanks but what is jo ,i get error,do i need to use some jar?

Comment: @Jean-You do not need to add any new jar. You need to pass the JsonObject for the static method. Have corrected the post now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the below code:

```
public void performExecute() throws IOException {        
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory(); 
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(jsonFactory); 
        File file = new File("json.txt"); 
        TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> typeReference = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}; 
        HashMap<String, Object> jsonMap = objectMapper.readValue(file, typeReference); 
        System.out.println("JSON DATA: " + jsonMap); 
    }
```

Make sure the Jackson library is in your class path & you imports the following classes while using the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.type.TypeReference;
```

Comment: @Sivan - how do i install the jackson library?\

Comment: You can download it from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksonjar.htm. Once you have downloaded the file successfully, extract the jackson.jar from jackson.jar.zip and add it to your application classpath.